# Get the id of an element by position using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Using javascript, is it possible to get the id of an element by its spatial position in the document using javascript?

Don't think its possible. But just wondering if it is.

Comment: just .id usually does the job. var elm = someElementInTheDom; alert(elm.id);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var x = 100, y = 100;
var id = document.elementFromPoint(x, y).id;
```

[Browser support.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t20)

Comment: Great solution! One thing to note though, if the pointer-event is set to none on that element, it will return nothing.

Answer (score 3):

This is crazy.  We have an answer so far using jQuery `.attr()` and one using javascript plain `.getAttribute()`.  While both will work, the most efficient way to get the id of a given element is simply:

```
element.id
```

It's a property of the object and there's no reason not to just access it as a javascript property.

You will, of course, have to obtain the DOM element itself before you can get the id.  You haven't shown us any HTML or told us how you access the element so we can't help with specifics there at all.  If you had a link and a click handler, you could get the id like this:

```
<a id="test" href="#" onclick="clickme(this)">Click Here</a>

function clickme(link) {
    var id = link.id;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can get the id of the element.

Using jquery u can get the id of the element

```
var id =$("element selector").attr("id");
```

see this exmaple

http://jsfiddle.net/6nsz6/

Comment: The question is about getting the `id`, not the element.